# Не работает альтернативный экранный буфер в Node.js

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, консоль

```
> node --version
v14.3.0
> uname -sr
Linux 5.4.41-1-lts
```

Не работают ansi escape-коды для создания альтернативного скрин буфера. Терминал поддерживает альтернативный буфер экрана, почти аналогичный код на Python работает.
Делаю так:

```js
let open_screen = () => process.stdout.write("\u001B[?1049h\u001B[H");
let close_screen = () => process.stdout.write("\u001B[?1049l");

open_screen();

let i = 0;                                    
let loop = setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.write('some text\n');
    i++;
    if (i >= 10) clearInterval(loop);         
}, 1000);

close_screen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалась проблема в невнимательности. Может кому-нибудь пригодится, т. к. по данной теме только один модуль на npmjs и тот не понятно как работает...

```
let open_screen = () => process.stdout.write("\u001B[?1049h\u001B[H");
let close_screen = () => process.stdout.write("\u001B[?1049l");

open_screen();

let i = 0;                                    
let loop = setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.write('some text\n');
    i++;
    if (i >= 10) {
        clearInterval(loop);
        close_screen();
    }      
}, 1000);
```